# Modal window (eg. <iframe>) through proxy

Tags: html, iframe, proxy

I want to make a modal window (eg. `<iframe src="www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>`) that would show blocked in my country domain (if, in this case, stackoverflow is blocked) -- kind of a "window" to a blocked website.

Any way to force iframe/javascript/website/host/domain/*anything* to access the blocked domain using proxy?

If that's not possible, any way to make website mirror, which would request the main domain through proxy?